# .htaccess short and friendly url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for the right `.htaccess` rule to make a Facebook.com/user URL like

What I want if I access for example

```
www.domain.com/StackOverFlow
```

It will be rewrite to

```
www.domain.com/index.php?category=StackOverFlow
```

Or

```
www.domain.com/category.php?item=StackOverFlow
```

Any help? I've tried some question here, but they doesn't explicit do this behavior.

Thanks in advance

Edited:

Forgot to say that I only want to be redirected using this rule, anything that after the domain, doesn't have any extension

For example it should redirect `www.domain.com/categoryDescription` but no `www.domain.com/categoryDescription.php` or `www.domain.com/categoryDescription.html`

Comment: There's an interesting tutorial on this here: http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example below takes the URI after `.com/` and assigns that to `$1`.
You can do the same for "item"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?category=$1 [L]
```

Comment: For example it should redirect `www.domain.com/categoryDescription` but no `www.domain.com/categoryDescription.php` or `www.domain.com/categoryDescription.html` will it work?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^StackOverFlow$ index.php?category=StackOverFlow [NC,L]
```

or:

```
 RewriteRule ^StackOverFlow$ category.php?item=StackOverFlow [NC,L]
```

In generally:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

or:

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ category.php?item=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: the `StackOverFlow` value was an example, it could be any category

Answer (score 3):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?category=x'.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: For example it should redirect `www.domain.com/categoryDescription` but no `www.domain.com/categoryDescription.php` or `www.domain.com/categoryDescription.html` will it work?