# Linking a file as a directory

Tags: php, html

I feel so dumb for not know what to call this...but I am trying to accomplish what I have seen here:
http://followerblast.org/terms/

Instead of terms.php, it is just "/terms/" I have tried googling EVERYTHING I can think of.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: They are sometimes called SEO-friendly URLs and are realized with `mod_rewrite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this

1. **htaccess(mod_rewrite)**, http://zenverse.net/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess/
2. **Folders**, Come on it's not a good way to do this it's really **dump**
3. **MVC & FWs** , if you are familiar with Frameworks and MVC SW Pattern then it will do this for your check **CodeIgniter** it's my favorite and simple

Also check this out 
[.htaccess short and friendly url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146062/htaccess-short-and-friendly-url)
I hope this can help :)

Comment: It would be nice if you added a comment on the down vote , I can be better :) and you will help

Comment: Originally downvoted because I felt you did not really answer the question but the linked SO question you added fits great

Comment: @mensi thanks for pointing it out, I wanted to be short and clear :)

Comment: Thank you for this, but Im still slightly confused. what If I just want to take http://www.mysite.com/terms.php and have that turn into http://www.mysite.com/terms/ ?

Comment: Check the linked question

Comment: I have, and that seems to be wanting to change it from /terms/ to /terms.php

Comment: I seem to understand now, thank you :)